# replacement rules applied to text - how to do it

Tags: text, sed

I have a text file such as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed. Viverra nam libero justo laoreet sit amet cursus. Amet est placerat in egestas. Viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum. Facilisis mauris sit amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum.
```

In this file I want to replace every occurence of a word by another word. The replacement rules are given in another file, eg.

```
s->c
or->ahahaha
et->123
```

and so on. Not that the replacement rule indicator `->` i can change to whatever need to be. What is the easiest way to do it in cli (linux)? -prefer no python, prefer one liner.
I do not even know how to ask, since for the keyword dictionary all python nonsense comes up.